# Ros installation of fuerte fails on OS X lion

Tags: macos, boost, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have boost installed, yet Cmake in build shared library, says it cannot find Boost. (I am using boost_1_48_0 ). Where should I put boost ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32312/ros-installation-of-fuerte-fails-on-os-x-lion/) by [marcalpv](https://answers.ros.org/users/2210/marcalpv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-04-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-04-21**:
Can you please be more specific ... post the errors, what is not compiling and are you using homebrew or macports?

**Comment by [marcalpv](https://answers.ros.org/users/2210/marcalpv/) on 2012-04-23**:
@Kevin, The install just cannot find the Boost Library every time its called in the installion of the ROS core libraries.. I am using Homebrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many issues with OSX and fuerte right now. Not everything compiles. Try editing CMakeLists.txt and add the directive to include and link the boost libraries.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1